# Boost - When interrupting thread, access violation occurs

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I have some code, that started in boost::thread. That thread is interrupted in some moment.

Thread code:

```
void CLifeSimLauncherDlg::hashFilesThread() {
    wstring *pathToMainDir = new wstring(L"./LifeSimGame");

    boost::this_thread::interruption_point();

    MyLib::hashFilesInDirExternal(doc, pathToMainDir,
        cpr);
}
```

Function `hashFilesInDirExternal` calling another function `hashFilesInDir`

```
void FileIO::hashFilesInDir(wstring dirn, pugi::xml_node *root,
    void(*calcHashFunction)(wstring, wstring, uintmax_t, pugi::xml_node*))
{
    try {
        long long int folderSize = 0;
        boost::replace_all(dirn, "\\\\", "\\");
        boost::replace_all(dirn, "\\", "/");
        boost::filesystem::path folderPath(dirn);
        if (boost::filesystem::exists(folderPath)) {
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr;

            for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dirIte(dirn); dirIte != end_itr; ++dirIte)
            {
                boost::filesystem::path filePath(dirIte->path());
                try {
                    if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(dirIte->status()))
                    {

                        hashFilesInDir(MyStrings::StringToWString(dirIte->path().string()), root, calcHashFunction);
                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                            (*calcHashFunction)(
                                MyStrings::StringToWString(dirIte->path().string()),
                                MyStrings::StringToWString(to_string(boost::filesystem::file_size(dirIte->path()))),
                                boost::filesystem::file_size(dirIte->path()),
                                root
                                );
                        }
                        catch (exception ex) {
                            MessageBox(nullptr, L"Some error occured on file hashing2.", L"Error:", MB_OK);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (exception& e) {
                    cout << e.what() << endl;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Some error occured on file indexing.", L"Error:", MB_OK);
    }

}
```

When thread interrupted, program fails with Access Violation Exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x005B3A1C in LifeSimLauncher.Main.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x005B3A1C.
```

at path.hpp, line 412, that contains code

```
path_traits::convert(&*m_pathname.begin(), &*m_pathname.begin()+m_pathname.size(),
        tmp);
```

this code is in the

```
#   ifdef BOOST_WINDOWS_API
    const std::string string() const
    {
      std::string tmp;
      if (!m_pathname.empty())
   /*This is 412 line*/     path_traits::convert(&*m_pathname.begin(), &*m_pathname.begin()+m_pathname.size(),
        tmp);
      return tmp;
    }
```

What I am doing wrong and how to prevent this exception?